# Hangouts APIs to check whether camera is turned off for all members in the group chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

As captioned.

Does Hangouts provide any API to check if all members in the group chat have turned off the camera?

The workflow that I am working on would need to ensure everyone's camera is off before starting.

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

No, Hangouts API doesn't provide that functionality, only the below actions/requests are supported which are explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/rest-api):

> spaces.get Returns a space. spaces.list Lists spaces the bot belongs
>   to.
>
> spaces.members.get Returns a member.
>
> spaces.members.list Lists humans (not bots) that belong to the space.
>
> spaces.messages.create Creates a message.
>
> spaces.messages.delete Deletes a message.
>
> spaces.messages.get Returns a message.
>
> spaces.messages.update Updates a message.